# Upper bound on an exponential function

Tags: exponential-function, upper-lower-bounds

I have a two-variable function $f(x,y)$ defined as:

\begin{equation}
f(x,y) := \frac{1}{x+1}\,\exp\left(-\frac{y}{x+1}\right), x\geq 0,\, y\geq 0.
\end{equation}

I want to show that this function for all $y\geq 1$ is upper bounded by $\left(y\exp(1)\right)^{-1}$. However, I am not able to find a starting point. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: for $t=\frac{y}{1+x}$, $f = y^{-1} t e^(-t)$. but since$xe^(-x)$ has its maximum on 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 
$g(x)
=xe^{y/x}
$
(essentially the reciprocal of this,
,
then
$g'(x)
=\dfrac{e^{y/x} (x - y)}{x}
$.

$g'(x) = 0$
at $x=y$
and is $> 0$ for $x > y$
and $< 0$ for $x < y$.
Therefore
$g(x)$ has a minimum at
$x = y$
of $ey$,
so
$\dfrac1{g(x)}
\le \dfrac1{ey}
$.